# Views not visible in ListView/Adapter, but are present debugging objects

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm struggling with this problem and didn' find any solution browsing the web and lots of other similar posts in StackOverflow

No error compiling, after a serach in the app no Views are visible in the ListView (browsing both ListView and CustomAdapter objects, result items views are present, but are not shown in the app's listview)

here the code:

## Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lightelements.carddroid">

<permission android:name="com.lightelements.carddroid.cards.provider.READWRITE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.lightelements.carddroid.cards.provider.READWRITE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
              android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/search_cards_title">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:authorities="com.lightelements.carddroid.cards.provider"
        android:name="com.lightelements.carddroid.CardProvider"
        android:exported="true"
          android:readPermission="com.lightelements.carddroid.cards.provider.READWRITE"
        android:writePermission="com.lightelements.carddroid.cards.provider.READWRITE"
        />
</application>

</manifest>
```

## res/xml/searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ 
    android"android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

## search_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchLayoutTestText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ListView android:id="@+id/searchResultsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

## simple_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/card_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/card_name"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

## SearchableActivity

```
package com.lightelements.carddroid;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by User on 20/09/2015.
 */
public class SearchableActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Card>> {

private static final String LOG_TAG = SearchableActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private CardsCustomAdapter mCardsCustomAdapter;
private static int LOADER_ID = 2;
private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
private List<Card> cardsRetrieved;
private ListView listView;
private String matchText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Entered Searchable Activity");

    setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);
    TextView testText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchLayoutTestText);
    testText.setText("OK SEARCHLIST LAYOUT");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // ACTION SEARCH PER CONFERMA SELEZIONE //
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"query: " + query);
        mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
        mCardsCustomAdapter = new CardsCustomAdapter(SearchableActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchResultsList);

        listView.setAdapter(mCardsCustomAdapter);
        matchText = query.toString();
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID++, null, SearchableActivity.this);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Card>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CardsSearchListLoader(SearchableActivity.this, CardContract.URI_TABLE, this.mContentResolver, matchText);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Card>> loader, List<Card> cards) {
    mCardsCustomAdapter.setData(cards);
    this.cardsRetrieved = cards;
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Card>> loader) {
    mCardsCustomAdapter.setData(null);
}
}
```

## MainActivity

```
package com.lightelements.carddroid;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks,
    BestPrice.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
TextView mData = null;
Fragment activeFragment = null;
LinearLayout activeLayout = null;

private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    // Connect to Database
    String[] projection = {BaseColumns._ID,
            CardContract.CardColumns.CARD_NAME,
            CardContract.CardColumns.CARD_SET,
            CardContract.CardColumns.SET_CODE,
            CardContract.CardColumns.MULTIVERSE_ID,
            CardContract.CardColumns.MKM_ID
    };
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor mTestCursor = mContentResolver.query(CardContract.URI_TABLE, projection, null, null, null);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Completato on Create.");

    if (mTestCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String card_name = mTestCursor.getString(mTestCursor.getColumnIndex(CardContract.CardColumns.CARD_NAME));
        TextView testView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
        testView.setText(card_name);
    }

}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            fragment = BestPrice.newInstance("param1", "param2");
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = "TEST SEZIONE 2";
            fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(number + 1);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(number + 1);
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
}

    public void dataSearch(View view){
    Activity fragment = (Activity) view.getContext();
    mData   = (TextView) fragment.findViewById(R.id.best_price_data);
    activeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_best_price_layout);
}

public void dataOut(String outData){
    mData.setText(outData);
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchCards);

        SearchView cardSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        cardSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Searchable created");

        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
}
```

## CardSearchListLoader

```
package com.lightelements.carddroid;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by User on 06/09/2015.
 */
public class CardsSearchListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Card>> {
private static final String LOG_TAG = CardsSearchListLoader.class.getSimpleName();
private List<Card> mCards;
private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
private Cursor mCursor;
private String mFilterText;

public CardsSearchListLoader(Context context, Uri uri, ContentResolver contentResolver, String filterText){
    super(context);
    mContentResolver = contentResolver;
    mFilterText = filterText;
}

@Override
public List<Card> loadInBackground() {
    String[] projection = {BaseColumns._ID,
            CardContract.CardColumns.CARD_NAME,
            CardContract.CardColumns.CARD_SET,
            CardContract.CardColumns.SET_CODE,
            CardContract.CardColumns.MULTIVERSE_ID,
            CardContract.CardColumns.MKM_ID
    };
    List<Card> entries = new ArrayList<Card>();

    String selection = CardContract.CardColumns.CARD_NAME + " LIKE '%" + mFilterText + "%'";

    mCursor = mContentResolver.query(CardContract.URI_TABLE, projection, selection, null, null);
    if (mCursor!=null) {
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int _id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                String card_name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(CardContract.CardColumns.CARD_NAME));
                int card_set = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(CardContract.CardColumns.CARD_SET));
                String set_code = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(CardContract.CardColumns.SET_CODE));
                int multiverse_id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(CardContract.CardColumns.MULTIVERSE_ID));
                int mkm_id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(CardContract.CardColumns.MKM_ID));
                Card card = new Card(_id, card_name, card_set, set_code, multiverse_id, mkm_id);
                entries.add(card);
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return entries;
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(List<Card> cards) {
    if (isReset()){
        if (cards!=null){
            mCursor.close();
        }
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"deliverResult");
    List<Card> oldCardList = mCards;
    if (mCards == null || mCards.size() == 0) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "++++++++++++++ No Ddata returned");
    }
    mCards = cards;
    if (isStarted()) {
        super.deliverResult(cards);
    }
    if (oldCardList != null || oldCardList != cards) {
        mCursor.close();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (mCards != null) {
        deliverResult(mCards);
    }

    if (takeContentChanged() || mCards == null) {
        forceLoad();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStopLoading() {
    cancelLoad();
}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    onStopLoading();
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.close();
    }
    mCards = null;
}

@Override
public void onCanceled(List<Card> cards) {
    super.onCanceled(cards);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void forceLoad() {
    super.forceLoad();
}
}
```

## CardsCustomAdapter

```
package com.lightelements.carddroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by User on 11/09/2015.
 */

public class CardsCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private static FragmentManager sFragmentManager;

    public CardsCustomAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager){
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    sFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}

public CardsCustomAdapter(Context context){
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_card, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    final Card card = getItem(position);
    final int _id = card.getId();
    final String name = card.getCard_name();

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_name)).setText(name);

    return view;
}

public void setData(List<Card> cards){
    clear();
    if (cards != null) {
        for (Card card : cards) {
            add(card);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ...

Comment: please try by giving some height manually to the list view like 200dp, just to check if its height issue for the list view

Comment: thanks for your advice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search layout heights should be inverted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchLayoutTestText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ListView android:id="@+id/searchResultsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this was one of the few things I didn't check :(
still some minor issues, but now something shows up

thank you very much